# can't read from database python

Tags: python, database

I have the following database:

```
{'numberOfExercises': {'quimica:D': 13, 'quimica:E': 12, 'quimica:B': 12, 'quimica:C': 12,
'quimica:A': 14, 'aventura:A': 0}, 'topicDone': {u'quimica:A': 2}, 'exercisePoints': 
{u'quimica:A:1': 1.0, u'quimica:A:4': 1.0}, 'exerciseTotal': {u'quimica:A:1': 1, 
u'quimica:A:4': 1}, 'toSend': {u'quimica:A:1': u'send_data(quimica, A, 1, 1.0)', 
u'quimica:A:4': u'send_data(quimica, A, 4, 1.0)'}, 'areaPoints': {u'quimica': (2, 2.0)}, 
'stage': {'level': 2}, 'topicPoints': {u'quimica:A': (2, 2.0)}}
```

the information I'm worry about is STAGE.

this is how I save it:

```
def save_stage(value):
    global stage

    stage['level']= value
    print stage
    __save_data__()

def __save_data__():
    global areaPoints
    global topicPoints
    global exercisePoints
    global topicDone
    global toSend
    global numberOfExercises
    global stage

    f = open('database.json', 'w')
    data = {'areaPoints': areaPoints, 'topicPoints': topicPoints,
            'exerciseTotal': exerciseTotal, 'numberOfExercises': numberOfExercises, 
            'exercisePoints': exercisePoints, 'topicDone': topicDone,
            'toSend': toSend, 'stage': stage}
    f.write(repr(data))
    print data
    f.close()
```

and this is how I get it:

```
def get_stage():
    return stage.get("level",0)
```

being 0 as the default value.

The thing is, when I call `get_stage()` when I have already saved something in the database (the last time I executed my program), it always returns 0. But when I executed `save_stage()` followed by `get_stage()` it has no problem reading from the database, any idea?

```
def __load_data__():
    global areaPoints
    global topicPoints
    global exercisePoints
    global exerciseTotal
    global topicDone
    global toSend
    global numberOfExercises
    global stage

    try:
        f = open("database.json")
        data = f.read()
        data = eval(data)
        f.close()
    except:
        data = {}

    stage = stage.get('stage', {})
    areaPoints = data.get('areaPoints', {})
    topicPoints = data.get('topicPoints', {})
    exercisePoints = data.get('exercisePoints', {})
    exerciseTotal = data.get('exerciseTotal', {})
    topicDone = data.get('topicDone', {})
    toSend = data.get('toSend', {})
    numberOfExercises = data.get('numberOfExercises', {})
```

Comment: OF course, what I'm trying to do is to get the database value anytime i call `get_stage()`, not only when i have already saved the information during the current program execution

Comment: When you finish running your program, everything goes away (if you are lucky) unless you persist it

Comment: I know that, the code I copied after "I have the following database:" is my database.json. The information is persisted, but somehow is not being read

Comment: Nowhere in this code that you've showed us is the data being read from the file. `f.write(repr(data))` writes the data to a file. Is there code similar to this that READS from that file? Perhaps when you start the program?

Comment: `def __load_data__():`
    `global stage`
    `try:`
        `f = open("database.json")`
        `data = f.read()`
        `data = eval(data)`
        `f.close()`
    `except:`
        `data = {}`
    `stage = stage.get('stage', {}))`

this is executed every time i run the program.

Comment: Edit you question and add `__load_data__()` formated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some `load_stage()` function to read data from `database.json`. And you have to save/read `stage['level']` value in some file.

**edit:**

`stage = data.get('stage', {})` in place of `stage = stage.get('stage', {})`

(`data.get` in place of `stage.get`)

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing with __load_data__() ?, besides, I have saved th stage value in database.json

Comment: It seems you load file but you not set `stage` and `stage['level']` or you set to `stage = stage.get('stage', {}))` so both give you `stage['level'] = 0` (default value)

Comment: i couldn't follow that, could you explain it again? what am I missing?

Comment: to set stage, i'm using the function `get_stage()`, but this is not reading from the database or i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Use `print stage` and `print stage['level']` after `stage = stage.get('stage', {})` in `__load_data__())` to test that value. Are they correct ?

Comment: mm somehow i'm getting "keyerror" when trying to print "stage['level']. but when i print the database i get: 'stage': {'level': 2}

Comment: by the way: is it correct `stage = stage.get('stage', {})` ? maybe it should be `stage = data.get('stage', {})` ? `stage.get` or `data.get` ?

Comment: oh my god, you're absolutly right! thank you so much! I can't believe that little error has been keeping me from going on with this program. Thank you!

Comment: if you are looking on text too long you don't see elementary mistakes :) Go on holiday :) And you can mark my answer as accepted.